# How to use lxml to get javascript code from a textarea?

Tags: javascript, python, html, parsing, textarea

I'm trying to extract javascript code from a textarea here is my code:

```
 def getCode(self,request):
    #print "Extracting URL: " + request
    opener = self.login(self.username,self.password)
    html = etree.HTML(opener.open(request).read())

    textarea = html.xpath('//*[@id="codeText"]/text()')        
    for code in textarea:
        return code
```

This is the html code I'm trying extract from:

```
<textarea onclick="javascript: this.select();" id="codeText" style="height: 300px;width:500px;">            <!-- Clickon Affiliate code start here -->
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://banners.clickon.co.il/LOVELY2_banners/swf/JWFLZxzNxjclWGP.swf?url=http://track.clickon.co.il/click/Q8uTE8BXZz1pskj/JWFLZxzNxjclWGP/TsQ8uTE8BXZz1pskjtS" width="728" height="90">
    <param name="movie" value="http://banners.clickon.co.il/LOVELY2_banners/swf/JWFLZxzNxjclWGP.swf?url=http://track.clickon.co.il/click/Q8uTE8BXZz1pskj/JWFLZxzNxjclWGP/TsQ8uTE8BXZz1pskjtS" />
    <param name="scale" value="exactfit" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
  </object>
  <img alt="" style="visibility: hidden;" src="http://track.clickon.co.il/imp/Q8uTE8BXZz1pskj/JWFLZxzNxjclWGP/TsQ8uTE8BXZz1pskjtS" />

</textarea>
```

if the textarea contain only links or a text my getCode function working great, but if it contains java script code I cant extract it.
Can you help me ?

Thanks,

Yaniv.

Comment: Do you want extract `javascript: this.select();` ?

Comment: No, I want to extract all what inside the textarea tags.

Comment: <textarea>I need all the html tags from here as html</textarea>

Answer (score 0):

In the code, `for` loop return too early; return only the first text.

If you want all the tags and text, try following.

```
import lxml.etree as etree

htmlchunk = '''
<textarea onclick="javascript: this.select();" id="codeText" style="height: 300px;width:500px;">            <!-- Clickon Affiliate code start here -->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://banners.clickon.co.il/LOVELY2_banners/swf/JWFLZxzNxjclWGP.swf?url=http://track.clickon.co.il/click/Q8uTE8BXZz1pskj/JWFLZxzNxjclWGP/TsQ8uTE8BXZz1pskjtS" width="728" height="90">
            <param name="movie" value="http://banners.clickon.co.il/LOVELY2_banners/swf/JWFLZxzNxjclWGP.swf?url=http://track.clickon.co.il/click/Q8uTE8BXZz1pskj/JWFLZxzNxjclWGP/TsQ8uTE8BXZz1pskjtS" />
            <param name="scale" value="exactfit" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        </object>
        <img alt="" style="visibility: hidden;" src="http://track.clickon.co.il/imp/Q8uTE8BXZz1pskj/JWFLZxzNxjclWGP/TsQ8uTE8BXZz1pskjtS" />

    </textarea>
'''

html = etree.HTML(htmlchunk)
textarea, = html.xpath('//*[@id="codeText"]')
print(textarea.text + ''.join(etree.tostring(code) for code in textarea) + textarea.tail)
```

output:

```
            <!-- Clickon Affiliate code start here -->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://banners.clickon.co.il/LOVELY2_banners/swf/JWFLZxzNxjclWGP.swf?url=http://track.clickon.co.il/click/Q8uTE8BXZz1pskj/JWFLZxzNxjclWGP/TsQ8uTE8BXZz1pskjtS" width="728" height="90">
            <param name="movie" value="http://banners.clickon.co.il/LOVELY2_banners/swf/JWFLZxzNxjclWGP.swf?url=http://track.clickon.co.il/click/Q8uTE8BXZz1pskj/JWFLZxzNxjclWGP/TsQ8uTE8BXZz1pskjtS"/>
            <param name="scale" value="exactfit"/>
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
        </object>
        <img alt="" style="visibility: hidden;" src="http://track.clickon.co.il/imp/Q8uTE8BXZz1pskj/JWFLZxzNxjclWGP/TsQ8uTE8BXZz1pskjtS"/>
```